# postman 404 Not Found

Tags: laravel, postman

I'm a beginner in laravel API I want to display list of articles (method index),I already created model Article, but I can not.

Hi, I'm a beginner in laravel API I want to display list of articles (method index),I already created model Article, but I can not.

**ArticleController**

```
<?php  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Article;
use App\Http\Resources\Article as ArticleResource;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $articles= Article::paginate(15);
        return ArticleResource::collection($articles);
    }
```

**create_table_articles**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

**ArticlesTableSeeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ArticalesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Article::class,30)->create();
    }
}
```

**ArticleFactory.php**

```
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Article::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->text(50),
        'body'  => $faker->text(200)
    ];
});
```

**App\Resources\Article.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Article extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         $this->call(ArticalesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**routes/api.php**

```
//list 
Route::get('articles','ArticleController@index');
//list single
Route::get('article/{id}','ArticleController@show');
//create article
Route::post('article','ArticleController@store');
//update articles
Route::put('article','ArticleController@store');
//delete article
Route::delete('articles','ArticleController@destroy');
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @LoganCraft i dont know how can i find error in postman,he just give me 404 | not found

Comment: Can you add your `routes`  to the question please

Comment: @atymic i update my code i add routes\api.php

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your postman request as well please?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles serve is start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel automatically prefixes routes in the `routes/api.php` file with the route prefix `/api`

You need to make a request to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/articles
```

Rather than

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles
```

You can change this in your `RouteServiceProvider` if your prefer:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L66-L72